# Is there a way (e.g. an Eclipse plugin) to automatically generate a DTO from an Entity (JPA)?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, code-generation, dto

I would like a plain forward DTO generation tool that would either

1. Generate it on the fly (e.g. cglib - create the class and DTO object on the fly)
2. Or an Eclipse plugin that will take the Entity and generate a DTO (user will specify which tree graph to include, and for non included, will include foreign keys instead of related entities etc)

E.g. take something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my_entity")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private RelatedEntity related;
     public RelatedEntity getRelated(){
          return related;
     }
     ...
```

And generate something like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my_entity")
public class MyEntity imlpements MyEntityDTO {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private RelatedEntity related;
     //overrides MyEntity interface, it's allowed to narrow return type 
     public RelatedEntity getRelated(){
          return related;
     }
     ...

     //implements MYEntityDTO respective interfaces

     public Long getRelatedId(){return related.getId();}
```

And DTO interface(s):

```
public interface MyEntityDTO {

    public String getId();
    public String getName();
    public Long getRelatedId();
    public RelatedEntityDTO getRelated(); //RelatedEntity implements RelatedEntityDTO

    ...
}

public interface RelatedEntityDTO {
    ... 
}
```

If we don't want to include children in the graph, remove it from the DTO interface:

```
public interface MyEntityDTO {

    public String getId();
    public String getName();
    public Long getRelatedId();

    ...
```

I'm sure there is some eclipse plugn for it and if not, I challange someone to write one, or explain why what I want is not helpful (and provide an alternative suggestion)

Comment: We don't have an IDE plugin yet, but Blaze-Persistence Entity Views(https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) uses interfaces just like you showcased it. At some point we are going to develop IDE plugins for this though. You can watch https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/issues/364 to receive an update on this matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably Hibernate Tools should be doing this: http://hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html

Comment: I could not find how, do you know that as a fact?

Comment: It said it writes an entire Seam application, so I'd say this is true and suggest Roo as the Spring alternative, but there is no non Spring/Seam plugin I could find... which is a little sad... :)
In any case this is the best answer at this moment...

Answer (score 2):

Telosys Tools can generate both : JPA entity and DTO

Let's have a look at this tutorial https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/springmvc-jpa-springdatajpa

it generates a full Spring MVC CRUD application with JPA
Architecture : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/springmvc-jpa-springdatajpa/presentation/architecture 
The mapper Entity/DTO is also generated (it uses "org.modelmapper" )

The templates are customizable

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at:
https://github.com/nikelin/spring-data-generation-kit

But it's only suitable for you if your project is under the 
Maven control.